# How do I use the testing package in go playground?

Tags: testing, go, go-playground

The `testing` package is available in the go playground.

How can I use the go playground to demonstrate testing concepts, without access to `go test`?

My assumption is it's possible using the testing.RunTests function. My attempts to do so always generate only "testing: warning: no tests to run".

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/PvRCMdeXhX

For context, my use case is for sharing quick examples of tests, examples and benchmarks with colleagues. I rely on go playground for sharing code snippets like this often.

Comment: See also [Go issue #6511](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6511) and especially [this snippet](http://play.golang.org/p/K0gFil6jFC) it refers to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `testing.Main`:

```
func main() {
    testSuite := []testing.InternalTest{
        {
            Name: "TestCaseA",
            F:    TestCaseA,
        },
    }
    testing.Main(matchString, testSuite, nil, nil)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/DQsIGKNWwd

If you want to use the "non deprecated", but unstable way:

https://play.golang.org/p/4zH7DiDcAP

Comment: Per the documentation, `testing.Main` is deprecated in favor of `testing.MainStart`.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Main - "Systems simulating "go test" should be updated to use MainStart."

Comment: They're both equally unstable (they're both intended for internal use only). So calling one "non-deprecated but unstable" is misleading.

Comment: Except `Main` is "preserved, as much as possible", per the documentation, whereas `MainStart` is "not subject to the Go 1 compatibility document".  So, yeah, it certainly seems like one is more stable than the other.

Comment: They're both internal functions, so the only way it could be construed as "more stable" would be that it's no longer being updated *because it's deprecated*. It's still an internal API not subject to the Go 1 compatibility promise.

Comment: Updated following changes to testDeps
https://play.golang.org/p/y5gMkY5xV_D

Answer (score 5):

[Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206116/3846997) still works as a manual way of invoking tests, but if you read the "About" tests are now automatically supported:

> If the program contains tests or examples and no main function, the service runs the tests. Benchmarks will likely not be supported since the program runs in a sandboxed environment with limited resources.

Comment: Use the dropdown menu to the right of the Share button to load an example test.

Answer (score 0):

There are execution time limits on playground and I believe they are less than the minimum execution time used by bench. From reviewing [the source of the `go test` command](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/test/test.go), it looks like the current proper entry point for tests is [`testing.MainStart`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#MainStart) which you may or may not have luck using. It is technically an internal-use API and not subject to compatibility guidelines, so YMMV.

Comment: Not from me, but this doesn't have much more than commentary. Plus dave does have 2 working examples, with both `testing.Main` and `testing.MainStart` (not that I'm recommending trying to simulate `go test` at all ;) )

Comment: The question doesn't have any code either and it's +2/-0, and Dave had the wrong (clearly indicated in the documentation) answer until I pointed it out. Oh well, the StackOverflow gods are fickle and inscrutable.